# Create a MongoDB server from a node.js script and leave it running

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a MongoDB server from a node script and leave it running so I can connect to it from another script.
I took [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#open) example:

```
var Db      = require('mongodb').Db,
    Server  = require('mongodb').Server;

var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017));
db.open(function(err, db) {
  if (err)
    console.log('Error');
  else
    console.log('Succes');
});
```

when i run it it displays `Error`
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Look into the `err` parameter, it'll tell you *exactly* what went wrong.

Comment: @BrendanAshworth : When I print the `err` parameter i get `Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]`. So it is not very helpfull for me.

Comment: @lonut it can help - that means your database isn't running on the same machine, port 27017. Double check your config and log files.

Comment: @BrendanAshworth : I guess I wasn't very clear in my question. The database does not exist, I want to create-it and run-it from a node script file. Is this possible or I'am just dreaming ?

Comment: You can't connect to a database that doesn't exist and it is *much* too infeasible to run the database from your script. I'd recommend looking for an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, I did not knew that.